# Not able to show user data in form, getting undefined method `user_path' (Using devise and simple_form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, simple-form

I'm trying to show the data from the user through a form so he can be able to edit any field. I'm using simple_form for this, and devise for authentication purposes.
I keep getting the `undefined method user_path` error.

This is my controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :authenticate_user!
 def index
 #Mostramos menu de opciones
 end

 def perfil
   @user = User.find(current_user.id)
 end

 def editar
   @user = User.find(current_user.id)
 end
```

end

The view for perfil.html.erb

```
<h1>showing user data</h1>
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :nombre %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
  <%= f.input :rut %>
  <%= f.input :ciudad %>
  <%= f.input :direccion %>
  <%= f.input :groupId %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Editar datos", :action => :editar %>
<br>
<%= link_to "Volver", :action => :index %>
```

And my routes file

```
devise_for :users
match "perfil" => "home#perfil"
match "editar" => "home#editar"
```

The error is around this line in the view `<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>` 
I've been searching for guides or insights on what I'm doing wrong (I'm almost sure is something bad done or missing in routes.rb). Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
```

This would post to the form to `users_controller` controller and action depending on the context. `devise_for :users` does not generate that controller for you, instead you have `registrations_controller` available and in fact, you don't need to create the edit form, there's already one available at url `users/edit` for the current user.

To customize the default templates, run `rails generate devise:views` and take a look at `app/views/devise`.

Comment: Great. I need just to change the routing in routes.rb, right?

Answer (score 1):

Change your routes as following and try,

```
    devise_for :users
    match "perfil" => "home#perfil", :as => :user
    match "editar" => "home#editar", :as => :user
```

The `:as` parameter tells the router what to name the route as (You can then add `_path` or `_url` to whatever the `:as` parameter is).

Also, any time you link directly to an ActiveRecord model (e.g. `link_to user.email, user`), it will try to turn `user` into `user_path`.

Answer (score 1):

if @user is an existing user, then

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
```

posts the form to user_path(@user) with PUT/PATCH http request type. 
Note that you need to create this route though. It is not clear from your code where this update action is, but if you used a resourceful pattern, then:

```
resources :users
```

takes care of it (routed via `UsersController#edit`), including your `perfil` and `editar` actions. BTW they look like they do the same: bring up a page to submit profile changes, normally routed done via `UsersController#edit`.